# Need help fixing my wp-config file

Tags: wp-config

I tried to edit my wp-config for a plugin. It didn't work and now my code in my wp-config is all wrong and my site can't read it. Any help with re-coding this correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sharing your unmodified `wp-config.php` is incredibly dangerous, it contains all your secret keys and DB passwords. I've taken steps to redact it from the revision history. You should notify your host immediatley that your Database and site has been compromised, change your DB details, and reset all user passwords, and get new security hashes. Doing so was a **major** security breach. If the site contains any personal information, you may need to contact your countries data protection regulator and notify them ( legal obligation in the UK, it may vary from country to country )

Answer (score 2):

Use wp-config-sample.php as a guideline. Rename your current wp-config.php file to wp-config-borked.php. Then copy wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php.

Then change the database name and credentials (user, pass) in the wp-config.php file.

**Never share your wp-config.php file.** It contains the 'keys to the kingdom'. If you have shared, change the database's credentials via hosting "MySQL Databases".